# Performance of a Asp.Net Webforms application using WCF Service for getting data from a CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sql-server-2008

Which disadvantages / problems might occur, if all content from a ASP.Net WebForms application was received through a WCF service, rather than through a direct database call?
(Entity Framework 4.0 as provider, SQL Server 2008 R2 as database)

A scenario would be content from a CMS. Instead of using a library which calls the database directly, I'm thinking of a WCF service that wraps the calls to the library.

Has anyone any experience with this and can tell me something about the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented several web applications where all the data is retrieved though WCF.  There are no noticeable performance impacts as long as your service is implemented well.

Comment: Good to hear ;) Did you notice any difference between running your WCF service under http or https?

Comment: I implemented one web application where all the WCF was done over HTTPS, and found the performance to be fine.